# Recommended CSS style Guide

Tags: html, css

Let we have a html like this;

```
<div class="mainElement">
  <div class="subElement1">...</div>
  <div class="subElement2">...</div>
  <div class="subElement3">...</div>
</div>
```

So if want to style that 'subElement1' which one is more standart or faster.

```
.mainElement > .subElement1{
  /*some CSS here..*/
}

.mainElement .subElement1{
  /*some CSS here..*/
}

.mainElement > div:first-child{
  /*some CSS here..*/
}
```

Comment: Tthe first would be fastest as it is the most specific....the "standard" is opinion...it will depend on the circumstances.

Comment: I would defenetly go with the first one if your want to reuse the subElement1. The last options would make the use of subElement1 unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ones you have, best is:

```
.mainElement > .subElement1{
  /*some CSS here..*/
}
```

because it targets direct child from parent class.

But if you really want performance, you want to target class directly:

```
.subElement1{
  /*some CSS here..*/
}
```

Or if you want even more faster code, use IDs:

```
#subElement1{
  /*some CSS here..*/
}
```

IDs are generally faster for browser to target, since they are supposed to be used only once per element.

Browsers read CSS from right to left, so adding a parent class/id unless you really need it, is only slowing down your code.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that right to left thing of browsers. I think I'm gonna use the first one option now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `.subelement1`?

If there is no reason to nest your selectors it is better off not to nest/couple them together.

But for your question it really depends on what you are trying to do the options you have posted all do different things.

The first one is fast and specific but selects only direct descendants of `.mainElement`

The second option selects all `.subelement1` classes that are within `.mainElement` which right now is only one element but you can keep nesting them inside of each other and they would all get the same styling not just the direct descendants.

As for the last one it is the most specific and could get you into trouble it finds the a `div` inside of `.mainElement` that is a `first-child` this could lead to trouble if you were to change the markup at all and say uses `span`s instead of `div`s also only the first child will always get that styling no matter what class you gave it.

Answer (score 0):

`.subElement` is enough, you shouldn't access the parent class first, cause it's affect to file size (althaough very small size) and make the css load file slower. Hope this link help you [Writing efficient CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS)